# What is the address of the main contract, deployed by the test contract in Foundry?

Tags: foundry

I want to check the balance of the contract I'm testing in Foundry with `address(contractAddress).balance`.

However, [from the docs](https://book.getfoundry.sh/forge/writing-tests) I only know the address of the test contract is `0xb4c79daB8f259C7Aee6E5b2Aa729821864227e84`.

How can I get the balance?

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to do this programmatically, you could wrap the contract creation line.

```
address(new Contract()).balance
```

`address(new Contract())` will return the contract's address. You could then save it to a variable, check its balance do all the other things with it.

Answer (score 0):

When the main contract is deployed in the test contract, this will show in the logs. If you run `forge test -vvvvv` with 5 v's the address of your main contract will be displayed after the yellow text `→ new`.

```
Traces:
  [#####] ContractTest::setUp() 
    ├─ [#####] → new Contract@[Contract address]
```

This would come from a test contract as this one:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

import "forge-std/Test.sol";
import "src/Contract.sol";

contract ContractTest is Test {
    Contract contract;

    function setUp() public {
        contract = new Contract(); // This line emits creates a log of the deployed address
    }

}
```